# How to specify rotated file location by using rotating-file-stream

Tags: node.js, logging, morgan

I have writtten code like below to log express logs.

```
const rfs = require("rotating-file-stream");

function formatDate() {
  var d = new Date(),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();
    hour = d.getHours();

  if (month.length < 2)
    month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2)
    day = '0' + day;
  if (hour.length < 2)
    hour = '0' + hour

  return [year, month, day, hour].join('-');
}

let log_directory = '/../logs/';

let log_date = formatDate()
let log_file_name =  path.normalize(__dirname + log_directory + log_date, 'access.log');

let accessLogStream = rfs.createStream(log_file_name, {
  size: "300M",
  interval: "1d",
})

app.use(morgan(':date[iso] :method :url :body :headers :remote-addr :req[content-length] - :status :response-time ms - :res[content-length] ', { stream: accessLogStream }));
```

logs are getting stored out side of the project as expected.

But after rotation, the logs are storing inside the project with the below folder names

```
20200507-0943-01-     
20200508-0943-01-      
20200509-0943-01-     
20200510-0943-01-      
20200511-0943-01-      
20200512-0943-01-      
20200513-0944-01-   
package.json
package-lock.json
public
routes
scripts
services
app.js
```

I don't want these folders created inside the project. Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are using a static file name as `filename` parameter of `createStream` function and you are doing some computation on date to have your resulting file name.

Please note that the computation on date happens only once, before calling the `createStream` function. In order to do computation on date happening at each rotation you should use a *filename generator function*. Details can be found in [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rotating-file-stream#filename).

More than this it seems there is a bug in this line: `path.normalize` accepts only one parameter.

```
let log_file_name =  path.normalize(__dirname + log_directory + log_date, 'access.log');
```

Last, to specify a directory for logging, [path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rotating-file-stream#path) option should be enough.

If I argued correctly your intentions, following code should solve all the problems

```
const rfs = require("rotating-file-stream");

function formatDate(d) {
  var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear(),
    hour = d.getHours();

  if (month.length < 2)
    month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2)
    day = '0' + day;
  if (hour.length < 2)
    hour = '0' + hour;

  return [year, month, day, hour].join('-');
}

function log_file_name(time, index) {
  if (!time) return 'access.log';

  return [formatDate(time), index, 'access.log'].join('-');
}

let accessLogStream = rfs.createStream(log_file_name, {
  size: "300M",
  interval: "1d",
  path: '/../logs/'
});
```